# Android RecyclerView: Update all items height after notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In `onCreateViewHolder` in my adapter class I'm distributing the overall height of the screen on the items I have like this:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_card, parent, false);
    // float weight = 1 / (mCards.size() * 1.0f);
    // LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, weight);
    // view.setMinimumHeight(params.height);
    int height = parent.getMeasuredHeight() / mCards.size();
    view.setMinimumHeight(height - 15);
    return new ViewHolder(view, listener);
}
```

But when I call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` only the new item gets the new height. All other (already existing) items stick with the old height.

Where should I move the height computing to be able to check it when the data set is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RecyclerView, **onCreateViewHolder()** gets called when a new view object is created and attached to the parent, **onBindViewHolder()** gets called when a view goes out of the screen while scrolling and a new view comes to the screen.

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> months = new ArrayList<>();

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> months){
    this.context = context;
    this.months = months;
}

@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View vi = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    Log.d("RECYCLER_CALLBACKS", "onCreateViewHolder() " + parent.getChildCount());
    return new ViewHolder(vi);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.month.setText(months.get(position));
    Log.d("RECYCLER_CALLBACKS", "onBindViewHolder() " + months.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    Log.d("RECYCLER_CALLBACKS", "onViewRecycled() " + months.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return months.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private CardView cardView;
    private TextView month;
    private TextView date;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        month = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    }
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerAdapter adapter;

private static int MONTH_COUNT = 1;
private ArrayList<String> monthsList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    monthsList.add("January");
    monthsList.add("February");
    monthsList.add("March");
    monthsList.add("April");
    monthsList.add("May");
    monthsList.add("June");
    monthsList.add("July");
    monthsList.add("August");
    monthsList.add("September");
    monthsList.add("October");
    monthsList.add("November");
    monthsList.add("December");

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, monthsList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            monthsList.add("New Month " + MONTH_COUNT);
            MONTH_COUNT++;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

}

[image]
Currently, only 6 items are visible on the screen. As soon as the app starts

> 08-26 21:32:23.547 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onCreateViewHolder() 0**
>
> 08-26 21:32:23.557 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onCreateViewHolder() 1**
>
> 08-26 21:32:23.557 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onBindViewHolder() February**
>
> 08-26 21:32:23.563 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onCreateViewHolder() 2**
>
> 08-26 21:32:23.563 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onBindViewHolder() March**
>
> 08-26 21:32:23.569 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onCreateViewHolder() 3**
>
> 08-26 21:32:23.569 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onBindViewHolder() April**
>
> 08-26 21:32:23.575 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onCreateViewHolder() 4**
>
> 08-26 21:32:23.575 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onBindViewHolder() May**
>
> 08-26 21:32:23.581 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: onCreateViewHolder() 5
>
> 08-26 21:32:23.581 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: onBindViewHolder() June

Initially, as the views are getting created, onCreateViewHolder() and onBindViewHolder() are called for each view. As we scroll down to the bottom

> 08-26 21:37:36.579 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onCreateViewHolder() 6**
>
> 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   **onBindViewHolder() July**
>
> 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   **onCreateViewHolder() 7**
>
> 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   **onBindViewHolder() August**
>
> 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   **onCreateViewHolder() 7**
>
> 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   **onBindViewHolder() September**
>
> 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   **onCreateViewHolder() 7**
>
> 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   **onBindViewHolder() October**
>
> 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   **onViewRecycled() January**
>
> 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   **onBindViewHolder() November**
>
> 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   **onViewRecycled() February**
>
> 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   **onBindViewHolder() December**
>
> 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   **onViewRecycled() March**

So, **onCreateViewHolder()** stops getting called after the 8th view, instead, **onViewRecycled()** is called which uses the same view which goes out of the screen instead of creating a new View.
Now, as we scroll back to the top:

> 08-26 21:54:20.262 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onBindViewHolder() March**
>
> 08-26 21:54:20.784 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onViewRecycled() December**
>
> 08-26 21:54:21.471 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.aftera nimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onBindViewHolder() February**
>
> 08-26 21:54:21.835 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onViewRecycled() November**
>
> 08-26 21:54:22.277 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onBindViewHolder() January**
>
> 08-26 21:54:26.050 28518-28518/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: **onViewRecycled() October**

As we scroll up, December goes out of the screen first and March comes in the screen. So,

1. December is recycled to give its place to March with the callbacks
   **onViewRecycled() December** and **onBindViewHolder()** March.
2. Similarly, November is recycled and February comes in its place with 
   the callbacks **onViewRecycled() November** and **onBindViewHolder() 
   February**.
3. And finally, **onViewRecycled() October** and **onBindViewHolder() January**.

Now, when we create a new Month, we call **notifyDataSetChanged()** to report the changes to the adapter:

> 2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   onViewRecycled() 5 2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: onViewRecycled() 4
>   2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   onViewRecycled() 3 2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: onViewRecycled() -1
>   2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   onViewRecycled() -1 2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: onViewRecycled() -1
>   2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   onViewRecycled() -1 2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: onViewRecycled() -1
>   2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   onViewRecycled() -1 2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: onBindViewHolder() July
>   2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   onBindViewHolder() August 2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: onBindViewHolder() September
>   2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   onBindViewHolder() October 2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: onBindViewHolder() November
>   2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   onCreateViewHolder() 5 2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: onBindViewHolder() December
>   2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS:
>   onCreateViewHolder() 6 2597-2597/com.stabstudio.afteranimation
>   D/RECYCLER_CALLBACKS: onBindViewHolder() New Month 1

As soon as **notifyDataSetChanged()** is called, all the views get recycled and **onCreateViewHolder()** is called again as many times as the **number of items displayed on the screen + 2**. 1 on top and 1 on the bottom of the screen which is not visible. In this case, it is only 8 times, no matter how many items are there in the **RecyclerView**.

So, you should move the height computing to **onBindViewHolder()** which gets called for all the views instead of onCreateViewHolder() which gets called only as many times as the number of items visible in the screen.

Comment: 'onBindViewHolder() which gets called for all the views'
This is what I'm actually was looking for.
Allow me to edit your answer to be more direct

Comment: Where is the option for that ?